# R: ggplot2 minus sign instead of hyphens (-) in ylim axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to change in ggplot2 ylim axis to minus signs (−) instead of hyphens (-). I tried many different options but still it does not show − sign and numbers in a plot..

```
plot <- ggplot(df_1, aes(x=t, y=RMS, color=Outcome, 
                                  fill=Outcome, shape=Outcome)) 
plot <- plot + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.02, 0.02),
                                      breaks=seq(-0.02, 0.02, by=0.01),
                                      labels=c("−0.02", "−0.01", "0", "0.01", "0.02"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the unicode glyph `\u2212`. Just swap it in using a custom labelling function inside `scale_y_continuous`

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = seq(-0.2, 0.2, 0.1)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_gray(base_size = 20) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.2, 0.2, 0.1), 
                     labels = ~sub("-", "\u2212", .x))
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me if I use ggsave to save to a file, but not in the RStudio graphics viewer (just get a blank pane). Any idea why?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva it may be that the font used in the viewer on your system does not support this particular unicode character. Perhaps try a different font family?

Comment: Slightly embarrassing.. 'update everything and restart' seems to have fixed this.  It was a weird problem though, ggplot worked fine except when I set the `labels` option in `scale_y_continuous`. I'll leave this here in case anyone else has the issue.