# ggplot2 true minus sign with superscript in axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, ggtext

Related question: [R: ggplot2 minus sign instead of hyphens (-) in ylim axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715900/r-ggplot2-minus-sign-instead-of-hyphens-in-ylim-axis)

I understand that the unicode glyph `\u2212` may be substituted for the hyphen to get a true minus sign in ggplot2 axis text, as the answer to the above linked question says. However, I need to place the minus sign in a superscript. Usually I use `ggtext::element_markdown()` but if I place the Unicode glyph, or the HTML entity `&minus;`, in between two `^^`, nothing displays. If `element_markdown()` is not a workable solution I would appreciate any other way of getting a true minus sign in my negative exponents in ggplot2.

### Example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

log_breaks <- 10^(-3:1)
log_labels <- c(paste0('10^\u2212', 3:1, '^'), '10^0^', '10^1^')
dt <- data.frame(x = 1, y = log_breaks)

ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = log_breaks, labels = log_labels) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

`log_labels` appears to be correct:

```
[1] "10^−3^" "10^−2^" "10^−1^" "10^0^"  "10^1^"
```

But axis text with the Unicode glyph in it does not display. The same result occurs if `&minus;` is used instead of `\u2212`.

[image: plot where negative exponents do not show up]

Comment: Slightly different for me, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE7gS.png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<sup>-1</sup>`.

```r
log_labels <- c(paste0('10<sup>\u2212', 3:1, '</sup>'), '10^0^', '10^1^')
ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = log_breaks, labels = log_labels) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: It is a journal formatting requirement to use the negative signs.

Comment: See my edit using `\u2212`, no change to the use of `<sup>`.

Comment: Interestingly this solution also works with `&minus;`. I guess the markdown `^^` somehow does not interact well with the special characters, but `<sup>` does?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where the boundaries exist, tbh. I'm as surprised as you about this one.